# How to bind mouse events on features drawn with L.Canvas in Leaflet 1.0?

Tags: leaflet

Leaflet 1.0 seems to support mouse events on individual features drawn on L.Canvas ([source code](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/layer/vector/Canvas.js#L251)). How should I bind an event with the `on()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same way you bind event handlers to any Leaflet layer, with [`on()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#evented-on):

```
var line = L.polyline(coords, {renderer: L.canvas()});
line.on('click', function(ev) {...} );
```